# Ng-click works on double tap only

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I am pressing twice on this ionic remove icon, then only it removes item. So please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my div that invokes the function "removeFromWishList(obj,$index) "

```
       <div class="col" ng-click="removeFromWishList(obj,$index)" > 
          <i class="icon ion-ios-trash-outline font_20px"  ></i>
        </div>
```

And this is my removeFromWishList(obj,$index) function in the controller

```
$scope.removeFromWishList = function (obj, index) {
  if ($scope.wishlistItems.indexOf(obj.id) > -1) {
    angular.forEach($scope.wishlistItems, function (val, key) {
      if (val == obj.id) {
        $scope.wishlistItems.splice(key, 1);
        Wishservice.remwishid(index);


      }
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    });
  } else {
    $scope.wishlistItems.push(obj.id);
  }
};
```

Comment: function removeFromWishList is called twice?

Comment: Ya actually that function will remove 1 item but actually it happens when i press twice.

Comment: `$scope.wishlistItems.splice($scope.wishlistItems.indexOf(obj.id),1)` can you try this to remove item from list? (assuming wishItems is list of ids, not object)

Comment: Thanks alot for the suggestion. Unfortunately it throws an error "Invalid or unexpected token" like this.

The error i can solve by writing a new function which calls this function two times , and then the new function will be called at remove botton press.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
$scope.removeFromWishList = function(obj, index) {
    var index = $scope.wishlistItems.indexOf(obj.id);
    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.wishlistItems.splice(index, 1);
        $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); // not sure why this is needed
    } else {
        $scope.wishlistItems.push(obj.id);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for working on this. But this code is not working(There are no errors)

Comment: It seems like something related to refreshing the content or something . Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide Plunker link? Also try commenting $state.go line in function.